# Leaflet issue: making layergroup of polylines not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

i got an issue with making polylines in my layergroup not clickable...
as you can see in the code below i use the built in function of leaflet to go through the layergroup (route.eachLayer), and try to add the style 'clickable: false' but this doesn't seem to do anything...

```
//route = layergroup with all polylines
function disableclicking(){
    route.eachLayer(function(layer){
        layer.setStyle({clickable: false});
    });
}
```

when i try to use this code, it seems to change nothing (it does go in the loop though)
or at least, it doesn't change what i want...

what i want is that the polyline's class '.leaflet-clickable' is removed... and this doesn't seem to happen. Doesn't this class change when you change the style to not clickable or is there something wrong with my loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar need and since the accepted answer has nothing to do with the question, I'll post the solution I came up with (in case somebody else arrives here from google).

```
function setClickable(target, value) {
    if(value && !target.options.clickable) {
        target.options.clickable = true;
        L.Path.prototype._initEvents.call(target);
        target._path.removeAttribute('pointer-events');
    } else if(!value && target.options.clickable) {
        target.options.clickable = false;

        // undoing actions done in L.Path.prototype._initEvents
        L.DomUtil.removeClass(target._path, 'leaflet-clickable');
        L.DomEvent.off(target._container, 'click', target._onMouseClick);
        ['dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mousemove', 'contextmenu'].forEach(function(evt) {
            L.DomEvent.off(target._container, evt, target._fireMouseEvent);
        });

        target._path.setAttribute('pointer-events', target.options.pointerEvents || 'none');
    }
}

setClickable(myLayer, false);
```